# Memory-efficient data structure for a set of integer tuples

Tags: python, data-structures, set, trie

I have a computational problem that involves a huge amount of integer tuples which I have to store in a set. In more details, the setting is:

- There is a positive integer `n` (<=10) and a lot of integer tuples of length `n`;
- I have a huge set `X` of such tuples, which is constructed in many steps;
- At each step I often check whether some tuple `t` is in `X`; if not, such tuples are added to `X` at the end of each iteration;
- I then have to iterate over the elements of `X` to do some other computations.

Up to now I have used Python built-in `set` class, and it was OK. The size of `X` got up to 5 millions entries, and this took about 3–3.5 GB of memory (the set `X` together with some additional data). I am facing the need to scale this up to 30–50 millions of entries (or more), so I am looking for a more memory-efficient data structure for this.

The requirements for this data structure thus are:

- Each entry appears only once;
- There is a fast membership testing and fast insertion;
- Iteration over all entries is not too hard.

The obvious candidate for such a data structure is a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), but the realisations I have seen do not fit my needs exactly. The best option seems to be [PrefixSet](https://pygtrie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#pygtrie.PrefixSet) from `pygtrie` (best documented, at least). But as the following short test shows, it actually takes at least 2—5 times more space.

```
from pygtrie import PrefixSet
from random import randint
from pympler import asizeof

t = PrefixSet()
s = set()

for i in range(100000):
    x = tuple(randint(0, 15) for _ in range(10))
    t.add(x)
    s.add(x)

print('|s|={} |t|={}'.format(asizeof.asizeof(s), asizeof.asizeof(t)))
```

Gives

```
|s|=16995032 |t|=75835376
```

So, apparently, it does not take advantage of the input data features (well, why should it? it a rather general purpose class).

> Question: what is the most memory-efficient set-like data structure for storing integer tuples of a fixed length? Which of such data structes are already realised in Python?

Comment: are the numbers in tuple limited to the range 0 to 10?

Comment: @JugalRawlani No, in theory there is no upper bound.

Comment: What happens if you try with significantly longer tuples? 10-tuples may just be too short to make up for the overhead of the trie. (I don't think the size of the integers themselves is relevant.)

Comment: Also, do you actually have to *store* the set, or can you just generate it on the fly during iteration?

Comment: i don't think you could get more efficient than a hash, but doing it yourself may give you more control over implementation tradeoffs. some other off the wall possibilities (with various tradeoffs/perf profiles): bitarray (for membership) + list, mmap'd hashed large file, a fast key/value database (something like foundationdb might be good here, but encoding/decoding tuples can take significant time), etc. those probably not as fast as a large in-memory data structure though....

Comment: @chepner For longer tuples things gets in favor of PrefixSet (well, for much longer tuples and when the number of elements and the bound on the integer values are not so big).

The data has to be stored, yes (the set is generated in chunks, the new one is based on the previous, and we want not to go over the same tuple many times).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to optimize memory usage, you will have to leverage patterns in your data.  Unless the distribution of values in your tuples is truly random, there should be some of the 10 positions that have fewer distinct values than others.  This is what tree structured storage can leverage to reduce memory usage.

For example, for 1 million tuples, if the first item in the tuples only have values 3, 5 and 9 across all tuples, storing 9-item suffix tuples in a dictionary of 3 sets should save the space equivalent to 999997 integers (in theory):

```
{
   3: set(of all 9-tuples that should be prefixed by 3)
   5: set(of all 9-tuples that should be prefixed by 3)
   9: set(of all 9-tuples that should be prefixed by 3) 
}
```

You could do this for multiple levels of prefix based on the x least distinct positions, up to a point where the overhead of dictionaries outweighs the economy.

```
{
   (3,7): set(of all 8-tuples that should be prefixed by (3,7) )
   (3,1): set(of all 8-tuples that should be prefixed by (3,1) )
   (3,4): set(of all 8-tuples that should be prefixed by (3,4) )
   (5,4): set(of all 8-tuples that should be prefixed by (5,4) )
   ...
}
```

Of course the least distinct items may not be the first ones so you may need a kind of mapping to reorder the positions in this dictionary.

The problem with testing this kind of storage optimization on randomly generated data is that the very randomness of the items defeats the purpose of the hierarchical storage and throws it in its worst case scenario.  Even if you do have some combination of positions that reduce the number of distinct values, it would still have to reduce the prefix size-count by more space than the added overhead of the hierarchical structure (my tests indicate that sets are very efficient in storing tuples of small integers so they would be hard to beat)

In short, if you know your data to have some patterns of distribution that would allow you to select a good level of grouping, you should be able to benefit from Trie or PrefixSet by mapping positions to their structure (and also not giving them the whole tuples to manage).  Otherwise it will be very difficult to achieve any meaningful memory savings.